# Habilitar acceso por URL a archivos de repositorio GIT en Cpanel

Tags: git, github, cpanel

He agregado un repositorio público a mi CPanel con la función [Git Version Control](https://docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/files/git-version-control/)

Únicamente creé el archivo `.cpanel.yml` dentro de mi repositorio, el cual contiene:

```
---
deployment:
  tasks:
    - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/usr_name/public_html/
    - /bin/cp -R * $DEPLOYPATH
```

Donde `usr_name` es mi nombre de usuario para acceder a CPanel.

Logro duplicar el repositorio con [Git Version Control](https://docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/files/git-version-control/), pero al momento de querer acceder a la carpeta que contiene los archivos de mi repositorio (usando mi dominio configurado en CPanel) me dice:

> 403 Access Denied

Los archivos del repositorio están guardados en una ruta similar a: `https://mydomain.com/repositories/app`, donde `app` es el nombre del repositorio.
Me he asegurado de que la carpeta `repositories` esté dentro de `public_html` de mi CPanel para que sea accesible mediante dominio, sin embargo al intentar acceder a un archivo .html de los que están dentro de `app` obtengo:

> 404
> Not Found
> The resource requested could not be found on this server!

*Ejemplo de URL: `https://mydomain.com/repositorioes/app/index.html`*

¿Me hace falta configurar algo para que los archivos de mi repositorio sean accesibles mediante mi dominio/Cpanel, o esto no se puede hacer?